# Can't set transparency to a RBG raster on QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster

I need to display an RGB raster on QGIS, with **Multiband Color** render type. After I set the **Contrast Enhancement** option to *No enhancement*, this is how the image is displayed.

[image]

No issues so far, since it is the correct visualisation.
Unfortunately, when I set the transparency to 50% the colours are totally altered, as you can see in the following image.

[image]

There is not a transparency band, therefore I have set the **Transparency Band** option to *None*. Also trying to assign specific transparency band the result is basically the same.

Comment: Which QGIS version is this?

Comment: I'm experiencing this issue in two different environments:

QGIS 2.6 Brighton on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and QGIS 2.8.1 Wien on Windows 7

In both cases the issue remains.

Comment: The reason I asked is that I seem to recall reading that this issue was fixed in newer versions. I'd give 2.8.3 a try.